# Spybot S&D finds Windows7 IE8 cookies that I can't find any other way. Where are they?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, cookies, spybot-sd

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium with IE8 (tried IE9 -- hated it.)

From the C:\ directory I can do `dir username@*.txt /s` and find a lot of cookies in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low -- I delete them. Then I run SpybotD&D -- it finds other cookies that I can't find with `dir` or `regedit.exe`

Where are these cookies stored? They're stored somewhere -- not only in IE8 memory -- because they persist after rebooting. Only Spybot can find and delete them.

In what super-secret location are these cookies stored?

Answer (score 0):

Found them. They're in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\index.dat`

To find them, do

`cd \Users\username

findstr /C:"username@known_cookie-site" /S * >results.txt`